# Put fingers over the mouth to silence someone

Tags: word-choice

How do I say in English when I put the index finger over the mouth as to silence someone?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you clarify, are you putting the finger over your own mouth or the other person’s? Is there any sound-making involved?

Comment: Put the fingers over my own mouth while I do a sound like:  sssshiiiiiii!!

Answer (score 1):

You **put your finger to your lips.**